# Match then exclude without lookbehinds

Tags: regex, rust

In Rust with the Regex crate, I've been trying to wrap my head around a regex expression to capture and extract things between square brackets `[]` yet exclude the brackets from the capture. Given:

```
// template[tags(foo,bar,baz)]
# template[replace_all(foo:bar)]
```

I'd like:

```
tags(foo,bar,baz)
replace_all(foo:bar)
```

I can easily get the `[]` capture group but i'm not understanding how to capture with an exclusion of characters after the match. I've been manually replacing these but it seems gross to me. I would love to be able to do it all in one expression.

Update: I am aware that I can get these in multiple capture groups but i'm really curious if there's a way to only capture the single one - hence exclude.

Looking over the docs i'm just not pickin up a way this can be done. There's a lot of great examples using look aheads and behinds but that doesn't appear to be apart of the rust regex crate. Am i missing something obvious here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `\[([^\]]+)\]` and use capture group

Comment: @isaactfa does my post need to literally say "input" and "output"? I thought that's what i've done here. Given an example input, and then my example output... what am i missing?

Comment: @archae0pteryx Sorry, that's my bad. I thought I was commenting under a different question.

Comment: @anubhava. This does work. The return `Some` is still showing both captures. The second one is what I'm after but It's because of the capture group that i'm getting 2 i think.

Comment: @isaactfa np! I was curious for when I review more than anything. lol. I thought there was something I was missing.

Comment: `still showing both captures` But there is only one capture group. You just need to grab capture group not the full match

Comment: @anubhava When putting `\[([^\]]+)\]` into https://rustexp.lpil.uk/ with the string `# template[tags(foo,bar)]` I am getting a `Some` with 2 results. Maybe my language is off here when i say "capture group". What i mean is the return from the capture.

Comment: @archae0pteryx That's just because every regex match has a "0th" capture group that is the entire match. You just need to extract the first capture group with the [`captures(_iter)`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures) method on `Regex`.